# How to enumerate the hypothesis search space in case of discrete valued input vector and binary label?

Tags: machine-learning

Some definitions used by the author in the example below:

**X** - It is a set of training examples, where each example is a feature vector with 6 features/attributes(Sky, AirTemp, Humidity, Wind, Water and Forecast)

**H** - set of all possible hypotheses that estimate the target function
f:X->y.

**EnjoySport** is the output label which is either Yes or No.

**Consider, for example, the instances
X and hypotheses H in the EnjoySport learning task. Given that the attribute
Sky has three possible values, and that AirTemp, Humidity, Wind, Water, and
Forecast each have two possible values, the instance space X contains exactly 3.2.2.2.2.2 = 96 distinct instances. A similar calculation shows that there are
5.4.4.4.4.4 = 5120 syntactically distinct hypotheses within H. Notice, however,
that every hypothesis containing one or more "$\phi$" symbols represents the empty
set of instances; that is, it classifies every instance as negative. Therefore, the
number of semantically distinct hypotheses is only 1 + (4.3.3.3.3.3) = 973.**

This excerpt is taken from Machine learning by Tom M. Mitchell. Ch-2, pg-23,24
I was unable to understand why 5 is there instead of 6 and also I am unable to follow semantically distinct hypotheses.

Comment: We lack a lot of context to understand the question properly, can you explain what EnjoySport learning task is ? What exactly is H and what are the hypothesis this extract is talking about ?

Comment: I tried to work it out but I give up. I don't know if there's any context but from the text it's just not clear. I can imagine what is meant by "semantically distinct" but there's no clue in the text. Imho whatever the point is, it's not a very good explanation.

Comment: I'm probably mistaken but to me the size of the hypothesis space is 2^96: number of possible subsets of X, i.e. number of possible ways to split X into two partitions (for target yes and no)